# If X'Y' term doesn't cancel, did I make an error?

Tags: calculus

In general, when rotating axes, if the X'Y' term does not cancel out, does that mean that a mistake was made in the geometry or algebra somewhere?

Comment: Probably you're mistaking with your algebra

Comment: @Alexei0709 Probably, or certainly?

Comment: You're right, certainly you did some wrong calculations. Just check out your algebra, I'm sure you'll find the mistake